# How do I earn the student badge?

Tags: support, reputation, badges

I do not understand this explanation of how to get to be a student.

> First question with a score of 1 or more

Is there an online manual with this info?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just upvoted your question. Now you should have a question with "a score of 1 or more".

While you are on this site, you will begin learning about how it works and things you can do.  When you ask a question and someone gives it an upvote, you get the badge "student".

When you answer a question and someone likes it enough to upvote it, you get a badge "teacher".

To the right of the box you enter questions, you'll see 4 numbers separated by dots.  Left click on those numbers and you will find some information about badges.

Comment: Can someone explain why I lost 28 reputation points on this answer?

Comment: Because the question (along with your answer) is migrated from askubuntu.com to meta.askubuntu.com (where this kinda questions should belong). At meta.askubuntu.com upvotes (or downvotes) don't increase (or decrease) user's reputation. So the reputation you earned for this answer at askubuntu.com was "corrected" once the Q&A was migrated to meta.askubuntu.com.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my approach to earning badges:

I just keep using the site, ask questions, answer questions, vote on stuff I like, edit, flag, ... and much much more.

Over time badges came in, one after the other. Mostly they were a real surprise. I had [to look up what I got them for](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges). For some of them I did not even know they existed. Some were introduced later and these were awarded to a lot of people all at the same time.

Only rarely I deliberately changed a bit of my behaviour in order to earn that badge: [Altruist](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/48/altruist), [Sportsmanship](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/61/sportsmanship) and [Vox Populi](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/79/vox-populi) are such examples.

But each except [Tumbleweed](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/40/tumbleweed) made me a bit happy. I believe this is the main purpose of badges.